# npx serve -s build -l 3000 is not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

```
npx serve -s build -l 3000
```

command to build my app in local at port 3000,

But when I ran this command it's throwing error like,

> await printUpdateNotification(args["--debug"]);   ^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
> at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:122:18)
> at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! Exit status 1

And in log also there is no proper error message, Can anyone suggest me the solution

Thanks

Comment: Which Node Version you're using. Can you update to the latest LTS version and check again?

Comment: @MCNaveen I'm using v14.7.0 nodee version

Comment: The latest LTS version of NodeJS is 16.16.0 (https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases)
Please update your Node to the latest version and check.

Answer (score 2):

Try force install the previous version of serve, solve my problem

```
 npm install serve@13.0.4
```